# Configurar PHPMailer com hotmail

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

Não estou conseguindo configurar meu email no `PHPMailer`, meu código esta assim:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.live.com"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP (caso queira utilizar a autenticação, utilize o host smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usar autenticação SMTP (obrigatório para smtp.seudomínio.com.br)
$mail->Username = '*********@hotmail.com'; // Usuário do servidor SMTP (endereço de email)
$mail->Password = '*********'; // Senha do servidor SMTP (senha do email usado)
$mail->Port     = 465; // SMTP port
```

O que estou errando?

Answer (score 4):

1° Verifique se o modulo do php openssl esta habilitado, o phpmailer precisa dele

2° Se for Gmail,Hotmail,Yahoo utilize a porta 587.

Exemplo de um Serviço meu que usa o hotmail:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "exemplo@htomail.com";
$mail->Password = "senhaAqui";
$mail->setFrom('paraquem@hotmail.com', 'Nome');
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@gmail.com', 'Reply');
$mail->addAddress('exemplo@hotmail.com', 'Exemplo2');
$mail->Subject = 'Titulo do Texto';
$mail->Body = 'Mensagem de texto';

if (!$mail->send()) {
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Posta essa classe require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

Comment: ela esta no projeto do github : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 1):

É necessário que ela esteja configurada da seguinte forma:

Link para download [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/)

**OBS:** É necessário liberar a porta 587

```
/**
        *String que armazena o email de onde partirá os emails (remetente).
        *@var string
        */
        const GUSER = 'email';

        /**
        *String que armazena a senha do email de onde partirá os emails (remetente).
        *@var string
        */
        const GPWD = 'senha';

        /**
        *String que armazena o email para qual as mensagens serão enviadas (destinatário).
        *@var string
        */
        const GSEND = 'teste';


       static function contactUsEmail(){

            $emailRemetente = $_POST['email'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $mensagem = $_POST["message"];
            $corpoMensagem = '<b>CONCTACT US EMAIL</b>'.'<br /><b>Email Remetente: </b>'.$emailRemetente.
            '<br /><b>Nome:</b>'.$name.'<br /><b>Assunto:</b>'.$subject.'<br /><b>Mensagem:</b>'.$mensagem;

            $sendResult = SendEmail::smtpMailer(SendEmail::GSEND, SendEmail::GUSER, $name, $subject, $corpoMensagem);

            if($sendResult === true){
                 echo 'Mensagem Enviada com Sucesso';
            }else{
                echo $sendResult;
            }
        }

        function smtpMailer($destinatario, $remetente, $nomeRemetente, $assunto, $corpo){

            /*
            *Objeto que realizará a composição do email com os dados passados como parametros, 
            *armazenara as configurações do servidor SMTP utilizado e todas as outras configurações 
            *e realizará o envio do email.
            *@var PHPMailer object
            */
            $mail = new PHPMailer();

            /**
            *Define o charset do email a ser enviado.
            */
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

            /**
            *Ativa SMTP para uso.
            */
            $mail->IsSMTP();

            /**
            *Não exibirá erros e mensagens, outras configurações possiveis: 
            *Debugar: 1 = erros e mensagens, 2 = mensagens apenas.
            */
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

            /**
            *Ativa a autenticação.
            */
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            /**
            *Protocolo utilizado, o gmail (servidor utilizado) requere o uso de tls.
            */
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

            /**
            *SMTP utilizado
            */
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

            /**
            *Porta utilizado para envio de mensagens (ela deverá estar aberta em seu servidor).
            */
            $mail->Port = 587;

            /**
            *Login do usuário utilizado para envio do email (no caso usuário comum do gmail).
            */
            $mail->Username = SendEmail::GUSER;

            /**
            *Senha do login de usuário utilizado para envio do email.
            */
            $mail->Password = SendEmail::GPWD;

            /**
            *Identificação do remetente do email (usuário de email utilizado para envio do 
            *email pelo sistema (logo de propriedade do sistema) e o nome do usuário remetente 
            *(informado na hora da criação do email)) do email.
            */
            $mail->SetFrom($remetente, $nomeRemetente);

            /**
            *Assunto do email.
            */
            $mail->Subject = $assunto;

            /**
            *Corpo do email.
            */
            $mail->Body = $corpo;

            /**
            *Email destinatário do email (de propriedade do sistema).
            */
            $mail->AddAddress($destinatario);

            /**
            *Seta o email como HTML (por padrão ele é text/plain).
            */
            $mail->IsHTML(true);

            $sendResult = $mail->Send();

            if(!$sendResult){
                return "<b>Informações do erro:</b> " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava testando essa autenticação, no servidor **redeHost** que era no do cliente, testei a mesma estrutura, no servidor da **locaWeb** que funcionou normalmente, o problema era a hospedagem da **redeHost**, que estava com algum bloquei do serviço.
Entrei em contato com o suporte da redeHost, me ajudaram a configurar com o próprio email que o cliente tem da hospedagem.

Fim da historia o problema era o SMTP, substituir de emal.dominio.com.br para smtpexc01.redehost.com.br